# Wordpress form results not showing

Tags: wordpress, forms

I am trying to use [this code](https://saika.li/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-form/) to add a form to a plugin I am writing. The plugin installs but when I click the submit button I don't get a response from the function. The code is shown below. It has the main file, the functions file and the class file. This is my first attempt at a WP plugin so I am probably making some silly mistake but I can't find what it is. Would someone please point out the problem?

```
    /*** MAIN PAGE ***/

    add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'My_viewer');

    function My_viewer(){
        $page_title = 'My_viewer';
        $menu_title = 'My_viewer';
        $capability = 'manage_options';
        $menu_slug  = 'my_viewer';
        $function   = 'my_functions';

        add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
        add_submenu_page( $menu_slug, $page_title, 'Panel', 'manage_options', 'my-panel-submenu-page', 'my_panel_page' );
    }

    function my_functions(){
       require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/my_functions.php';
    }
    function my_panel_page() {
        require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/class-my-class.php';
        $page = new My_class( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );

    ?>
      <div class="wrap">
       <h1><?php esc_html_e( 'Main Panel', 'access-log-viewer' ); ?></h1>
       <?php $page->DisplayPanel(); ?>
      </div>
    <?php
    }


    /*** FUNCTIONS FILE ***/

    function traitement_formulaire_don_cagnotte() {
     if ( ! isset( $_POST['cagnote-don-envoi'] ) || ! isset( $_POST['cagnotte-verif'] ) )  {
      return;
     }

     if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['cagnotte-verif'], 'faire-don' ) ) {
      return;
     }

     $don = intval( $_POST['don'] );
     $url = wp_get_referer();

     // Donation amount is too low.
     if ( $don < 0 ) {
      $url = add_query_arg( 'erreur', 'radin', wp_get_referer() );

     // Donation amount is too high.
     } elseif ( $don > 10000 ) {
      $url = add_query_arg( 'erreur', 'trop', wp_get_referer() );

     // Everything's OK, let's do the work...
     } else {
      $cagnotte_actuelle = intval( get_option( 'valeur_cagnotte', 0 ) );
      update_option( 'valeur_cagnotte', $cagnotte_actuelle + $don );
      $url = add_query_arg( 'success', 1, wp_get_referer() );
     }

     // Redirect user back to the form, with an error or success marker in $_GET.
     wp_safe_redirect( $url );
     exit();
    }
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'traitement_formulaire_don_cagnotte' );

    /*** CLASS FILE ***/

    class My_class {
      public function __construct( $plugin_basename ) {
      }
      
      public function DisplayPanel() {
        if ( isset( $_GET['erreur'] ) ) {
         $error = sanitize_title( $_GET['erreur'] );

         switch ( $error ) {
          case 'radin' :
           $message = __( 'We need a positive amount.', 'msk' );
           break;

          case 'trop' :
           $message = __( 'Thanks, but we do not need that much money.', 'msk' );
           break;

          default :
           $message = __( 'Something went wrong.', 'msk' );
           break;
         }

         printf( '<div class="error"><p>%1$s</p></div>', esc_html( $message ) );
        }
        ?>
        <form action="#" method="POST" class="comment-form">
         <?php wp_nonce_field( 'faire-don', 'cagnotte-verif' ); ?>

         <div>
          <label for="don"><?php _e( 'Amount donation' ); ?></label>
          <input id="don" type="number" name="don" value="5" />
         </div>

         <input id="submit" type="submit" name="cagnote-don-envoi" id="submit" class="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Submit', 'msk' ); ?>" />
        </form>
          <?php
          ?> <pre> <?php
        print_r($_GET);
        ?> </pre> <?php
      }
    }
```